# Composition of Polynomials in Bernstein Form

Tags: polynomials

I am unable to find the reference, but I once had material with an algorithm for composing univariate polynomials in Bernstein form, directly producing the resulting sequence of coefficients.

I'm finding that the "blossoming" based approach is somewhat hard to digest and implement correctly, and have been trying to recover the simpler version that used only binomials (if I can recall correctly, that is).

#### EDIT:

I've found it!
For reference, it is: [T. DeRose, Composing Bezier Simplexes](http://graphics.pixar.com/people/derose/publications/ComposingSimplices/paper.pdf)

However, I'm also looking for other versions. I had a somewhat long paper on the subject of root finding that had a simpler, more elegant presentation, though I can't recall the author's name.